# I do not understand why the value of the variable result is nonzero in this Java question

Tags: java, integer, double

I have this question:

What do you think would be the value of the variable result after executing the following segment of Java code?

```
int i = 1234567890;

float f = i;

int result = i - (int)f;
```

> *The answer is nonzero*

Bear in mind I am a beginner in java currently learning the absolute basics and frankly I do not understand why the answer is nonzero and what each line of the code actually means?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## tl;dr

If you want accuracy in your fractional numbers, use [`BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html) class rather than the `float` floating-point type.

## Floating-point is inaccurate

The floating-point technology used by `float`/`Float` and `double`/`Double` [trade away accuracy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#Accuracy_problems) for speed of execution. Never use these types where accuracy is important, such as money.

So converting an integer to a floating-point number and back again may not result in the same number.

This behavior is *not* specific to Java. Java implements the [electrical engineering standards defining floating-point arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) behavior. Any programming language supporting standard floating-point will show the very same issue.

```java
int i = 1234567890;                  // Create an integer number from literal input, and store as a primitive value in variable named `i`. 
float f = i ;                        // Convert the integer `int` primitive to a fractional number represented using floating-point technology as a primitive value in variable named `f`. 
int backAgain = (int)f ;             // Cast (convert) from a `float` type to a `int` type. Data-loss may be involved, as any fraction is truncated. 
int result = i - backAgain ;         // Subtract one `int` primitive from the other `int` primitive. Store the integer result in a primitive `int` variable.
boolean isZero = ( result == 0 ) ;   // Test if the result of our subtraction is zero.
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/W9Rvhu).

```
i: 1234567890
f: 1.23456794E9
backAgain: 1234567936
result: -46
isZero: false
```

## `BigDecimal`

If you want accuracy rather than speed when working with fractional numbers, use [`BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html) class.

```java
int i = 1234567890;
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal( i ) ;
int backAgain = bd.intValueExact() ;
int result = i - backAgain ;
boolean isZero = ( result == 0 ) ;
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/CXTbC8).

```
isZero: true
i: 1234567890
bd: 1234567890
backAgain: 1234567890
result: 0
isZero: true
```

Comment: So why does converting a float number back to an int not yield 0 as the result?

Comment: @computerscienceisapain Because that is not the job of a floating-point number. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format As a beginner, I suggest you simply accept this reality and move on. You can revisit the issue when you understand more about binary versus decimal representations of numbers.

Comment: Thank you Basil. Can I also ask why the int 1234567890 converted to a float number gave 1.23456794E9 instead of 1234567890.0? Is there a range that a float type is permitted to?

Comment: @computerscienceisapain The main lesson to learn here is to not program by intuition; instead **read the documentation**. Nowhere in the documentation for `float` will you find a promise of fidelity when converting to/from integers. You invented that assumption. The [promise made to you](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) was "single-precision 32-bit IEEE 754 floating point". (Actually, the formal promise made to you is the [*Java Language Specification*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/), section *4.2.3. Floating-Point Types, Formats, and Values*.)

Comment: @computerscienceisapain The range and behavior of a [single-precision 32-bit IEEE 754 floating point number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) is explained in that Wikipedia page I linked. You can also search Stack Overflow for much more discussion, as this topic has been addressed many many times.